# Get all posts from a Tumblr blog using jQuery getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr, getjson

I want to get all text posts of a Tumblr blog with jQuery getJson using Tumblr's API.

I tried using the following code, but I just got 20 posts:

```
function loadPosts () {

  var key = "api_key=xBcVPLfdDKpH0GjMCd1whW7rPoYkzLgZD3ZwpzndISFI4huSpA"
  var api = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/only-text-posts.tumblr.com/"
  var post_amount

  $.getJSON(api + "info?" + key,function(data) {
    post_amount = data.response.blog.posts
    $.getJSON(api + "posts/text?&filter=text&limit=" + post_amount + "&" + key,function(data) {
      $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {
        var content = item.body
        $("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + content + '</li>')
      });
    })
  })

}
```

Here is a good sample Tumblr blog for testing:

http://only-text-posts.tumblr.com/

Comment: Please add your code and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jgillich Sorry, This is my first question on StackOverflow. I'm now all clear about the rules, Thank you so much.

Comment: Just wanted to say, if you're doing this in a theme you could just exclude the other post types that you don't want to display/output (other than text posts) in the theme itself. I'm not sure what your end game is though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#text-posts), only up to 20 posts are returned. You can specify an offset with the `offset` parameter, and retrieve all posts with several calls:

```
function loadPosts () {

    var key = "api_key=your_key";
    var api = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/only-text-posts.tumblr.com/";
    var retrieve_more = function (offset) {
        $.getJSON(api + "posts/text?callback=?&filter=text&limit=20&offset=" + offset + "&" + key,function(data) {
            $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {
                var content = item.body;
                $("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + content + '</li>')
            });

            if (data.response.posts.length == 20) {
                retrieve_more(offset + 20);
            }
        });
    };

    retrieve_more(0);
}

loadPosts();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33eBc/)

Answer (score 1):

As from the [Tumblr Api documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) there is a limit of 20 posts per request. You can perform multiple requests with an increasing offset.

```
var max_posts_per_page = 20;
$.getJSON(api + "info?" + key,function(data) {
    post_amount = data.response.blog.posts;
    for (var offset = 0; offset < post_amount; offset += max_posts_per_page) {
        $.getJSON(api + "posts/text?&filter=text&limit=" + max_posts_per_page + "&offset=" + offset + "&" + key,function(data) {
            $.each(data.response.posts, function(i, item) {
                var content = item.body
                $("#Posts ul").append('<li>' + content + '</li>')
            });
        });
    }
});
```